# How to debug Chrome extension example with code injection?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

maybe this question is a bit noob style but I don't understand this JavaScript stuff.
My question: how do I debug injected code of the following
[chrome extension example](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/examples/api/downloads/download_links.zip)?
The file popup.js executes send_links.js (this is the injected file, if I understand this correct). I would like to debug send_links.js. I cannot set any breakpoint because I cannot see send_links.js in the Developer Tools of Chrome. I tried the command "debugger;" in send_links.js but it does not work. "console.log("blah");" commands are ignored too.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure you're looking at the right log? The background page, popup, and page with content script all have separate logs. If you put a `console.log` in your injected script and it doesn't show up in your page's console, you're either 1) not reaching the instruction in the code (e.g., due to a syntax error) or 2) you're not actually injecting your script.

Comment: The code is executed (the extension is working). But 2) is possible. Ok, how to do this?

Answer (score 6):

The `debugger` keyword will work if you open the Developer Tools for the current tab before you press the action button.

Also, if you want the script to display with its name, add the following line anywhere in `send_links.js`:

```
//@ sourceURL=send_links.js
```

Then the script will show up in the 'Content Scripts' tab of the Developer Tools of the current tab. There you can set breakpoints and such. But you need always to open the Developer Tools for the tab before pressing the button for this to work.

Answer (score 4):

All `Injected Files` or `Content Scripts` are Exposed to Page `Developer Tools`, You can set breakpoints and all regular stuff you do on regular Java Script Pages.

[image]
<sub>(source: [google.com](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/scripts-files/scripts_panel_navigator.png))</sub>

All your console log(s) appear in the page they are injected.

### Ex:

If i inject `console.log(document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style);` to http://www.google.co.in/, then i need to open devtools of http://www.google.co.in/ page and look in its console.

[image]

The Output appeared is similar to regular debugging result.

## EDIT 1

They are exposed through [chrome.tabs.executeScript()](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript) but indirectly, when you set `debugger;` command you can inspect code.

## Demonstration

If some sample code injects

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(35, {
    "code": "console.log('hi');debugger;//@ sourceURL=send_links.js"
});
```

debugger of page shows the script being injected.

[image]

Comment: Does that include scripts that are injected using `chrome.tabs.executeScript`? I agree that the console output is there but it does not show the script itself.

Comment: Yes, they can be if you use the //@ SourceURL convention. See my answer to this question.

Comment: @BeardFist:They are exposed to dev tools check my **EDIT 1**

Comment: wouldn't that only work if the code was bug free? If there were any syntax errors it wouldn't execute `debugger`.

Comment: @BeardFist:If there are syntax errors `debugger;` doesn't work either in regular stuff; , my intention here is not to talk of syntax errors and debugger behavior, it is about exposure of code to devtools through `executeScript` API.

Comment: I was just trying to say that injecting it normally would work in all cases as he would like to `debug` the code. If there was a syntax error the code would not be exposed to dev tools and he would have no way to see what line caused the error, whereas injecting it through `content_scripts` would have the code exposed to begin with and thus any syntax errors as well. The question was more about how to debug than how to expose.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's because you open the debugger tool on the tab and not on the extension. Right click on the icon of your extension and choose the **Inspect popup** menu item. You can find more informations on this page http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_debugging.html

Comment: I tried inspecting the "icon" but there is no inspection function. If I follow your link I reach the source `popup.js` - where I can step through but I don't reach `send_links.js`

Answer (score -1):

In this case the script is not injected until you open the popup. Once the popup window loads, it injects `send_links.js`, which in turn sends a message as soon as it is done getting the links. You could reverse this messaging and inject the file in the manifest:

```
"content_scripts": [{
  "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
  "js": ["send_links.js"]
}],
```

add an on message handler to `send_links.js` with support to send a response

```
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(message,sender,sendResponse){
  [...]
  sendResponse(links);
});
```

and then replace the `onMessage` handler and `executeScript`  in the popup with a `sendMessage` callback

```
chrome.windows.getCurrent(function (currentWindow) {
  chrome.tabs.query({active: true, windowId: currentWindow.id},function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab[0].id, {method: "getlinks"},function(links){
      for (var index in links) {
        allLinks.push(links[index]);
      }
      allLinks.sort();
      visibleLinks = allLinks;
      showLinks();
    });
  });
});
```

This arrangement will put `send_links.js` into every page so that you can debug it more easily. Once it is bug free you can switch back to programmatic injection because in cases like these it is more efficient. 
You can find the script under Sources > Content Scripts > One of them (`plfdheimenpnchlahmhicnkejgmhjhom` for example).

[Edited source files](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/12636410/download_links.7z)

Comment: instead of `chrome.windows.getCurrent(function (currentWindow) {chrome.tabs.query({active: true, windowId: currentWindow.id}` you could use `chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}` which is a shorter version

Comment: @Sudarshan I agree, I just wanted to change as little of the code as possible and the example was using it like this.